# "group by" on json data (special structure)

Tags: javascript, json, group-by, sum

I've data from students in json that I need to **sumup by types (here below EP) and show as percentage** of the maximum score, using only javascript.

```
{
"document_title":"NOTE",
"teacher_name":"AM",
"assignments":[
    {
        "date":"15 jan. 2014",
        "abbr":"EP1",
        "title":"Epreuve 1",
        "type":"EP",
        "max":"100"
    },{
        "date":"16 jan. 2014",
        "abbr":"EP2",
        "title":"Epreuve 2",
        "type":"EP",
        "max":"60"
    }],
"students":[
    {
        "name":"Apprenant 1",
        "points":["75","47"]
    },{
        "name":"Apprenant 2",
        "points":["18","35"]
    },{
        "name":"Apprenant 3",
        "points":["95","57"]
    },{
        "name":"Apprenant 4",
        "points":["60","26"]
    }],
"history":[],
"history_index":0
}
```

I can't figure out how to do ...

Comment: this might help http://jslinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://lodash.com/docs#groupBy

Comment: JSLINQ seems to do exactly what I need. I'll test. Thks for your comments:-)